# What does "you like stick" and "I like aerosol" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, colloquialisms, ellipses

This is a part of a song named *Fools* by Australian singer Troye Sivan. I don’t get the meaning of the third line. I get the literal meaning of *stick* and *aerosol*, but I don’t think a piece of wood and some pressurized liquid makes any sense here. So what are *stick* and *aerosol*, then?

> Oh, our lives don’t collide, I’m aware of this
>   The differences and impulses and your obsession with
>   **the little things: *you like stick, and I like aerosol***

Comment: Link to the entire lyrics?

Comment: @Mitch It might be more helpful to have the actual song: https://youtu.be/vfD96yRT8cs?t=1m26s I think it's easier to understand why whoever wrote the song chose "aerosol" instead of "spray".

Answer (score 11):

**Stick** and **aerosol** are two different types of [deodorant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deodorant):

[image: Stick deodorant (courtesy of wikipedia.org)]
<sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/16/Stick_deodorant.jpg/330px-Stick_deodorant.jpg))</sub>
[image: Spray deodorant (courtesy of wikipedia]

Personally I'd call aerosol deodorants "spray" deodorants instead, which tallies with the articles you get when you google [is aerosol deodorant better than stick?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&ei=t8ppWuvxF6iFgAbJpovACQ&q=is%20aerosol%20deodorant%20better%20than%20stick&oq=is%20aerosolstick%20deodorant&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i8i7i30k1.71621.75659.0.77227.10.10.0.0.0.0.76.596.10.10.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.10.594...0j0i7i30k1j0i67k1j0i13k1j0i13i30k1j0i8i13i30k1.0.XlQ0j-sTkzg).

Comment: I have a hunch that Americans tend to say "aerosol" rather than "spray" for deodorants. Your Google is probably British.

Comment: You could flag the OP and ask for it to be migrated, which is what I suggested in my close vote. I didn't want to close the question but I thought it was rather a simple question, which would have been more helpful over at ELL.

Comment: And Troye Sivan himself has lived in Australia since age 2, so don't ask what Americans say.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think Americans tend to use "spray" as well because aerosol is a mouthful. It's probably just that aerosol just fit better with the rhythm than "spray": https://youtu.be/vfD96yRT8cs?t=1m26s

Comment: I'll dare to speak for Americans: we're more likely to say "spray" than aerosol. (Sorry, but this has me laughing.)

Comment: @ColleenV - A mouthful of aerosol is definitely something to be avoided ;)